# What is migi's physical composition

Tags: parasyte

I am just wondering, what is migi made of i just was watching parasyte and was wondering.

Comment: Digitally-composited pixels, I'd imagine. (Unless you're talking about the manga, in which case I guess it'd be ink and paper.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Parasytes are alien organisms, made of alien cells that have similar biochemistry to ours (they feed off of our food - or us).

These cells have several properties (powers if you may):

- All of them work as brain cells. The intellect of a parasyte is varied, but directly proportional to its size. It is shown when Migi divides, the divisions are dumber.
- All cells can differentiate freely. They can work as muscles, elongate and become hair, stiffen and harden as much as metal, work as sensory organs, etc. This is the source of the morphing power of parasytes.
- Generate telepathic/empathic signals. Parasytes can communicate empathically with one another, by sending signals. When previously agreed on, they can coordinate actions to great efficiency.
- Information transfer

  - > Gotou gestalt of parasytes can freely transmit information from one another, including granting control of one's own body to another parasyte. Migi "downloaded" several parasyte-bytes of information while in Gotou's collective, and thinking on that information is one of the reasons he went into final hybernation.

Parasyte cells also have several weaknesses:

- Do not reproduce: parasyte cells cannot reproduce (mitosis). This makes the size of parasytes fixed and limited. Any permanent damage permanently reduces the size of the creature, with some side effects, as

  - > Migi's hibernation after he used part of his cells to heal the chest wound Shinichi receives from the Parasyte that killed his mother.
- > Chemical vulnerability: Parasytes do not have the same immunities granted by specialized cells such as lymphocytes and chemicals like antibodies, and their chemistry is rather simplistic. This makes them vulnerable to several chemicals and pollutants.

  - > This is what caused Gotou's death, infection from a rusted metal object + pollutants.